# ASP.NET Boilerplate MVC 5.x template fails to start

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, aspnetboilerplate

After downloading ASP.NET MVC 5.x template, I update the connection string, restore NuGet packages and then try to run `Update-Database` command in Package Manager Console, but I consistently get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Castle.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I was able to solve this once by removing all packages and adding them back one at a time, but this is extremely time-consuming.

I have had this same experience with both the Angular and Multipage versions, and I am using VS2017 Community.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162944/discussion-between-jacob-hulse-and-aaron).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> in the Web project's web.config it reads:
>
> ```xml
> <dependentAssembly>
>   <assemblyIdentity name="Castle.Core" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc" culture="neutral" />
>   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
> </dependentAssembly>
> ```

You can remove that binding redirect.

Comment: Thanks again for helping me find the solution!

Comment: Make sure the Web project has been also set up as Startup Project. Otherwise it will keep on complaining the same error again and again assuming your startup project is set to other then Web project.