# I write a test case in Aspnetboilerplate application. when run the test case It gives error about Unable to resolve dependencies

Tags: c#, unit-testing, aspnetboilerplate

I get this error after running a test case in C# Aspnetboilerplate application. there is a problem with Castle.Core package. How would I fix this error?

> Could not load file or assembly 'Castle.Core, Version=4.1.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   [2/28/2018 10:10:42 AM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:01.3681076]
>   -------- System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'Castle.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) [2/28/2018 10:10:42 AM
>   Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:01.3759779]       Stack Trace:

Comment: Don't post just errors like this.
Post a bit of description about what you have done.

Comment: Check the version in csproj file. Or try to update Castle.Core

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Boilerplate MVC 5.x template fails to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179819/asp-net-boilerplate-mvc-5-x-template-fails-to-start)

Comment: It's not work. I remove binding redirect. but still get the error.

Comment: Restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

This a general dependency management issue that can arise when working with NuGet!

Try adding the required assembly version redirects to App.config or Web.config. (Sometimes, NuGet does this automatically for you sometimes you need to manually do that) See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions.

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Castle.Core" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```